# Is the correspondence between our universe and cellular automata in the presence of time travel just co-incidence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, cellular-automaton

I've written [a paper](http://www.ifost.org.au/~gregb/essays/aitc.pdf) discussing a modification to the [game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life). Essentially, the traditional game is modified so that a cell is alive if there are 5 or 6 alive neighbours in total across the generation before *or after* it. Apart from becoming computationally intractable, the resulting universe has a speed of light limit, Mach's principle, virtual particles, an EPR-paradox-like correlation-at-a-distance, an arrow of time, a similarity between time and spatial dimensions, and a hideous renormalisation problem.

It doesn't have any equivalent to the double-slit experiment.

Is there any reason why this should have come so close to our universe? Is there any other research in this area?

Comment: The game of life doesn't satisfy any conservation laws as far as I can tell. It's about the poorest model for physics imaginable. It's not homogeneous, it's not isotropic, it doesn't have Lorentz invariance. It has the wrong dimensionality and it's not linear, unlike the physical universe, which is microscopically time reversal invariant, it's not even that. One can't predict the previous state from the current one... there is not one element in there that makes sense to a physicist.

Comment: This model is microscopically time reversal invariant.

Comment: So you are only lacking five of six? OK. That it doesn't reproduce quantum behavior properly is because it doesn't follow the proper dynamical equation. Look into Feynman path integrals for an idea what a system has to do to behave quantum mechanically.

Comment: Indeed yes, and that's why I think this is kind of interesting. Missing five out of 6 the fundamental requirements you mentioned and the model still has quite a lot of high-level features from our reality -- which aren't there in typical cellular automata (which lack 6 out of 6). Is that co-incidence, or is there something deeper going on?(P.S. I'm aware that it doesn't fully reproduce quantum mechanics -- it can't generate a double-slit experiment, for example.)

Comment: What's missing ARE the fundamental requirements for physics. We aren't looking for toy systems but for correct descriptions of nature.

Comment: @GregBaker I'm assuming you are the author of the paper? If so, you should disclose that. I've edited your post accordingly. In any case, this appears to be off topic since this site is not the place for review of non-mainstream ideas. Since your paper doesn't appear to be published in a reputable journal, nor does it even cite any prior work appearing in reputable journals, it definitely meets our criteria for being considered non-mainstream.

Comment: Ups: I wrongly declined a spam flag before noticing the self-link.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks. It was suggested to me that the physics stackexchange would be the appropriate place to discuss this, but clearly it isn't. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing, is metaphorically like a "Wick rotation" of an ordinary cellular automaton. A Wick rotation in the complex plane transforms real time to imaginary time, and the metric signature from Lorentzian to Euclidean. Similarly, your cellular automaton is arguably all space directions and no time direction.

It's an old idea that quantum mechanics might somehow be due to loops in time (e.g. classical Wheeler-Feynman absorber theory), and in my opinion your framework does deserve investigation. Could it, for example, reproduce some sort of Wick-rotated Ising model? You should talk to people who work on spin chains.